# What are the pom.xml and log4j.properties under Apache CXF for?

Tags: apache, maven, cxf, pom.xml

I am new to Webservices and I need to know what the pom.xml and log4j.properties files are for in an Apache CXF project. I read the POM is used to represent a Maven project so it holds configuration files, dependencies etc. Is that correct? Why would I use Maven bulid instead ob sinpl runnig it as a Java application. And what is the .properties file for?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pom.xml` is used to build (ex. create .jar files) the project using Maven. It it not used at runtime.

`log4j.properties` is a runtime configuration, that defines what logging information should be written and where. Check out these examples: http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the POM file. It is a "Project Object Model" that holds the configuration files, dependencies. I use it because you can do a mvn clean install, instead of doing it separately, it splits the code into modules, dependency-relationships and versions.

log4j.properties is an open source API that is used to specify where you want your logs to be redirected. For example:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

will make all your logs be output in the console.

If you want it to be saved in a file, use:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```